# redrawing polygon after adding points on edges and dragging those points draws weird lines

Tags: javascript, sorting, svg, d3.js, polygon

I have co-ordinates for the points by taking which I draw a polygon. I can add points on the edges of the polygon and when I drag any point it should drag only the connected lines. As points can be added later on the edges so the point co-ordinates need to be ordered and the polygon should be redrawn by taking the ordered points so that on dragging any point the lines connected to the dragged point only should be dragged. So to order the points I am sorting my co-ordinates(2D-points) clockwise using  Graham Scan/ sorting by polar angle.

My sorting code is
I find the center of the polygon like

```js
function findCenter(points) {
  let x = 0,
    y = 0,
    i,
    len = points.length;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    x += Number(points[i][0]);
    y += Number(points[i][1]);
  }

  return { x: x / len, y: y / len }; // return average position
}
```

Then I sort the points by finding angles of each point from the center like

```js
function findAngle(points) {
  const center = findCenter(points);

  // find angle
  points.forEach((point) => {
    point.angle = Math.atan2(point[1] - center.y, point[0] - center.x);
  });
}

//arrVertexes is the array of points
arrVertexes.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.angle >= b.angle ? 1 : -1;
  });
```

But the problem I am facing is if I drag any point more towards opposite side and add a new point on the edges afterward and drag the newly added point the sorting of co-ordinates is not ordered exactly because of which there is a flickering while dragging.

Here is a pictorial view of the problem I am facing for quick understanding.

Initially my svg looks like

[image]

After this I add a point and dragged like

[image]

Then I added one more point like

[image]

once I drag the added point it redraws my polygon something like

[image]

Actually It should be like

[image]

Here is the link for my play area

```
`https://codepen.io/jinata92/pen/MWyoepo?editors=0010`
```

So I am looking for a solution that won't give me weird redrawing of the lines. Only the connected lines to the dragged point should be dragged.

Answer (score 0):

I have applied closest point on polyline algorithm and found the index of the added point from the array of points where each point is involved in making a line which is polyline.

```js
/* desc Static function. Find point on lines nearest test point
   test point pXy with properties .x and .y
   lines defined by array aXys with nodes having properties .x and .y 
   return is object with .x and .y properties and property i indicating nearest segment in aXys 
   and property fFrom the fractional distance of the returned point from aXy[i-1]
   and property fTo the fractional distance of the returned point from aXy[i]   */
function getClosestPointOnLines(pXy, aXys) {
  var minDist;
  var fTo;
  var fFrom;
  var x;
  var y;
  var i;
  var dist;

  if (aXys.length > 1) {
    const getI = (n1, n2) => {
      let i;
      const a1 = aXys[n1];
      const a2 = aXys[n2];
      if (a1[0] != a2[0]) {
        let a = (a1[1] - a2[1]) / (a1[0] - a2[0]);
        let b = a1[1] - a * a1[0];
        dist = Math.abs(a * pXy[0] + b - pXy[1]) / Math.sqrt(a * a + 1);
      } else dist = Math.abs(pXy[0] - a1[0]);

      // length^2 of line segment
      let rl2 = Math.pow(a1[1] - a2[1], 2) + Math.pow(a1[0] - a2[0], 2);

      // distance^2 of pt to end line segment
      let ln2 = Math.pow(a1[1] - pXy[1], 2) + Math.pow(a1[0] - pXy[0], 2);

      // distance^2 of pt to begin line segment
      let lnm12 = Math.pow(a2[1] - pXy[1], 2) + Math.pow(a2[0] - pXy[0], 2);

      // minimum distance^2 of pt to infinite line
      let dist2 = Math.pow(dist, 2);

      // calculated length^2 of line segment
      let calcrl2 = ln2 - dist2 + lnm12 - dist2;

      // redefine minimum distance to line segment (not infinite line) if necessary
      if (calcrl2 > rl2) dist = Math.sqrt(Math.min(ln2, lnm12));

      if (minDist == null || minDist > dist) {
        if (calcrl2 > rl2) {
          if (lnm12 < ln2) {
            fTo = 0; //nearer to previous point
            fFrom = 1;
          } else {
            fFrom = 0; //nearer to current point
            fTo = 1;
          }
        } else {
          // perpendicular from point intersects line segment
          fTo = Math.sqrt(lnm12 - dist2) / Math.sqrt(rl2);
          fFrom = Math.sqrt(ln2 - dist2) / Math.sqrt(rl2);
        }
        minDist = dist;
        i = n1;
      }
      return i;
    };

    const updateI = (n1, n2) => {
      const newI = getI(n1, n2);
      if (newI !== undefined) {
        i = newI;
        return true;
      }
    };

    for (let n = 1; n < aXys.length; n++) {
      updateI(n, n - 1);
    }
    if (updateI(aXys.length - 1, 0)) i = aXys.length;

    if (i < aXys.length) {
      let dx = aXys[i - 1][0] - aXys[i][0];
      let dy = aXys[i - 1][1] - aXys[i][1];

      x = aXys[i - 1][0] - dx * fTo;
      y = aXys[i - 1][1] - dy * fTo;
    }
  }

  return { x: x, y: y, i: i, fTo: fTo, fFrom: fFrom };
}
```